# C# using and return

Tags: c#

Hi I was wondering can I do this in C#?

```
public MemoryStream d()
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        return ms;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write that code, but it probably wouldn't do what you are thinking. The MemoryStream is going to be disposed of before the return (that is the finally aspect of the using statement). As a result, nothing from the MemoryStream will be available and calling any of the associated methods that require interaction will cause an exception.

So yes, you can do that. However, you really should not because it will cause problems.

Essentially what you have written is this

```
public MemoryStream d()
{
    MemoryStream ms;
    try
    {
        ms = new MemoryStream()
    }
    finally
    {
        ms.Dispose();
        return ms;
    }
}
```

Hopefully that more clearly shows what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you will get `ObjectDisposedException` when you try to use the returned `MemoryStream`.

BTW, why didn't you just try it out?